# Proofs from the Book - need quick explanation

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients

I've been recently reading this amazing book, namely the chapter on Bertrand's postulate - that for every $n\geq1$ there is a prime $p$ such that $n<p\leq2n$.

As an intermediate result, they prove that $\prod_{p\leq x}p \le 4^{x-1}$ for any real $x\geq2$, where the product is taken over all primes $p\leq x$ . While proving that, they rely on the inequality
$$
\prod_{m+1<p\le2m+1}p\leq\binom{2m+1}{m},
$$
where $m$ is some integer, $p$'s are primes.

They explain it by observing that all primes we are interested in are contained in $(2m+1)!$, but not in $m!(m+1)!$. The last part is what I don't understand.

I can understand how this principle can be applied to the bound $(2m+1)!/(m+1)! = (m + 2)\ldots(2m+1)$, but why can we safely divide this by $m!$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you're analysing too much for the last part?

If we look at the inequality 
$$
\prod_{m+1<p<=2m+1}p\leq\binom{2m+1}{m},
$$

we see that for any prime $p \in (m+1,2m+1]$, we have $p|(2m+1)!$ but $p\nmid m!$ and $p \nmid (m+1)!$. ["The last part" that you mention is simply because $p > m+1$.]

So $p$ is indeed a factor of the numerator of $\binom{2m+1}{m}$ but not in its denominator, which proves the inequality.

Comment: Ok, I think I can see now more clearly. The task is to find for the product some good-looking upper bound. This upper bound should obviously contain all primes in the product. Binomial coefficient is obviously integer and it does contain all primes we are interested in, since nominator contains them by definition of factorial, and denominator doesn't for the same reason and so denominator can't eliminate any prime factor of the nominator that we are interested in. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the last question is that ${a\choose b}=\frac{a!}{b!(a-b)!}$ is known to be an integer, for all integers $a, b$ satisfying $a\ge b\ge 0$.  The reason is that it is counting the number of ways to choose $b$ out of $a$ objects.  This is necessarily an integer.

Comment: I know that. I now see that I thought denominator can eliminate some prime factor of interest from the nominator. Anyway, thank you for your answer.